# How to store data on android for fast retrieval

Tags: android

I am trying to write an application that retrieves data that the user has stored. Whats the best way to store this data. The data has a large number of rows but each field has very little data. Initially I was thinking of using Sqlite , but the read calls I believe are very slow and need to be implement in a background thread according to [Vogella's thread](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

I need extremely quick retrieval rate.

Are there any other option for me?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is not slow. It's practically immediate for my quiz app with thousands of entries.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for the options and details on them.